# ArrayList - I can't resolve this red line code

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

before the code as follows

```
class MainAdapter(val locationList: ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    val byDates = locationList.groupBy { it["time"] }  //this fine 

 }
```

after that i change to use model

```
class MainAdapter(val locationList: ArrayList<Model>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

   val byDates = locationList.groupBy { it["time"] }  //this red line i cant resolve

}
```

and this my model

```
data class Model(val name : String?,
                        val address : String?,
                        val time : String?)
```

Comment: ok solve with this change.


val byDates = locationList.groupBy { it.time }

Answer (score 1):

It's because in the first (working) example `it` refers to an instance of `HashMap<String, String>`, thus calling `it["time"]` is actually equal to calling `it.get("time")`.

In the second example however, `it` refers to Model. In Kotlin, you cannot access properties by "brackets" syntax (like in JS for example), thus it shows an error. The correct code would be `locationList.groupBy { it.time }`.